# Remove old records based on date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    cf.CLIENTID, p.Id as ProfileID, t.TITLEDESC as Title,
    cf.ClntForenme as Name, cf.CLNTSURNME as Surname, 
    pm.Lender, pm.Product, pm.LenderReference,
    pm.AmountRequested as LoanAmount,
    pm.DateCompleted, 
    CASE 
       WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) AND GETDATE() 
          THEN 'Completed under a year ago'
       WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())) AND (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) 
          THEN 'Backlog WOM 1 Year'
       WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())) AND (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())) 
          THEN 'Backlog WOM 2 Year'
       WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -4, GETDATE())) AND (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())) 
          THEN 'Backlog WOM 3 Year'
       ELSE ''
    END Source,
    CASE 
       WHEN pm.Id > 0 THEN 'Check Perspectiove for ERC'
       ELSE ''
    END ERC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID
FROM 
    tbl_Profile as p
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Profile_Mortgage as pm ON p.id = pm.FK_ProfileId
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_ClientFile as cf ON p.ClientId = cf.CLIENTID
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].tbl_DDTitles as t ON cf.CLNTTITLE = t.titleid
WHERE 
    pm.MortgageStatus = 7 
    AND p.CaseTypeId = 1
    AND pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -4, GETDATE())) AND GETDATE()
```

This query returns 990 records.

Some clients will have multiple profiles (`ProfileID`) what I want to do is only show me the `ProfileID` with the latest `DateCompleted`.

So, for instance, I have a clientID of 5566 this client has 3 profiles each with there own Datecompleted i only want to see the last profiles information based on Datecompleted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for you is to partition your data by `client`, `profile`, then check which `datecompleted` is the greatest value (aka whichever ones have a `DateRank` of 1). Then just select those that have that value as 1.

```
select * from
(
    SELECT cf.CLIENTID ,p.Id as ProfileID,t.TITLEDESC as Title,cf.ClntForenme as Name,cf.CLNTSURNME as Surname,pm.Lender,pm.Product,pm.LenderReference,pm.AmountRequested as LoanAmount,
    pm.DateCompleted, 
     CASE 
    WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (select dateadd(year, -1, getdate())) AND getdate() THEN 'Compelted Under a year ago'
    WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (select dateadd(year, -2, getdate())) AND (select dateadd(year, -1, getdate())) THEN 'Backlog WOM 1 Year'
    WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (select dateadd(year, -3, getdate())) AND (select dateadd(year, -2, getdate())) THEN 'Backlog WOM 2 Year'
    WHEN pm.DateCompleted BETWEEN (select dateadd(year, -4, getdate())) AND (select dateadd(year, -3, getdate())) THEN 'Backlog WOM 3 Year'
    ELSE ''
    END Source,
    CASE 
    WHEN pm.Id > 0 THEN 'Check Perspectiove for ERC'
    ELSE ''
    END ERC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CLIENTID, ProfileID order by DateCompleted desc) as DateRank --Changes here
    FROM tbl_Profile as p
    INNER JOIN tbl_Profile_Mortgage as pm
    ON p.id = pm.FK_ProfileId
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ClientFile as cf
    ON p.ClientId = cf.CLIENTID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].tbl_DDTitles as t on cf.CLNTTITLE = t.titleid
    WHERE pm.MortgageStatus = 7 and p.CaseTypeId = 1
    AND pm.DateCompleted between (select dateadd(year, -4, getdate())) AND getdate()
) clientinfo
where clientinfo.DateRank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks allot much appreciated

Comment: Tips: `(select dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))` can be simplified to `dateadd(year, -1, getdate())`. Using `between` with `datetime` often leads to issues with time-of-day. Explicit comparisons are generally preferable. Since `case` "evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied", you don't need to check two conditions in each `when` clause, just the first `when`. To avoid confusion when using multiple `GetDate()` calls it helps to capture a single value, e.g. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();`, and use that value throughout.